# test.xlsx couldn't be downloaded - EPPlus

Tags: vb.net, epplus

When I try to open test.xlsx created by the code below, I get "test.xlsx couldn't be downloaded". That said, if I choose to save the file, I am able to save and open the file just fine.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

```
    Dim pack As New ExcelPackage
    Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Test"

    pack.SaveAs(ms)

    ms.WriteTo(Context.Response.OutputStream)

    Context.Response.Clear()
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xlsx")
    Context.Response.StatusCode = 200
    Context.Response.End()
```

Comment: What program do you have set to open .xlsx files by default?

Comment: MS Excel and Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sample code should do the job:

```
Using pkg = New ExcelPackage()
    Dim ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1")
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hello"

    Dim buf = pkg.GetAsByteArray()

    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xlsx")
    Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("*.xlsx")
    Response.BinaryWrite(buf)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.[End]()
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but you write your file to `Response.OutputStream` then call `Response.Clear`, so I'm thinking your respose headers are being sent with no content (no file) which is why it says "couldn't be downloaded".

Try moving the `ms.WriteTo` to just before `Response.End`